# How to hide parent's method from the particular children in TypeScript?

Tags: oop, typescript

I’d like to hide some parent’s methods from particular ancestors.
However, I can’t figure out how to do that.

Let’s say we’ve got:

```
class GrandPa {
   // must not be accessible from the GrandSon:
   protected gradPaDoing() {}
}

class Parent extends GrandPa {
   // Here probably must be some kind of adapter between GrandPa and GrandSon...
}

class GrandSon extends Parent {
   grandSonDoing() {
      this.gradPaDoing(); // I'd like to make it impossible
   }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: you can make them private to hide them from everyone but GrandPa, but you can not  selectively hide them.

Comment: I'm thinking about some kinda adapter between GrandPa and GrandSon...

Comment: it would break liskov's substitution pricinciple. If you would do that a GrandSon could not behave the same as a GrandPa. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: maybe inheritance is not the right tool to use in this case. If you could give more context as to why you would like this we could help you find another solution.

Comment: @toskv, I want to rename some method for consistency and prevent using the old ones.

Comment: if deprecation is what you are looking for why not make a @Deprecated decorator you could slap on methods. It could log something when the method is used to warn the users they should be using something else.

Comment: an example https://gist.github.com/michelsalib/cfff8114ce081930a453

Comment: @toskv, thanks! There I go!

Comment: when you find a solution please post it as an answer as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your design has a flaw. Consider changing your design, if possible.

What I mean is: visibility is not supposed to be reduced down the hierarchy. It may be, however, increased if there need be. Just think about it, and it will make sense.

What you can do instead is, remove that grandPaDoing method all together from the ancestor class. Move it to an interface. And make your leaf classes implement that interface only if they need that behavior.

This approach will be cleaner, more consistent and more OOP way.

EDIT:

This solution still works for the case you mentioned in your comment. Here is how:

Let's say you want to rename anOldMethod to aNewMethod and prevent old method to be used anymore.

Then simply:

step1) create an interface, add aNewMethod into this interface and then make your leaf classes implement this interface.

step2) delete anOldMethod form parent class. If method is not there, it can not be accessed anymore. If you want, you can deprecate them by @Deprecated, as @toskv suggested.

Comment: I want to rename some method for consistency and prevent using the old ones.